# Index per user or Index for all users (different schemas)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been listening to everybody saying that's better to share a same index for all users instead of a index per user. So each user would an alias.

From then on, I've ever guess that's the best solution for several reasons. However, It comes me up a situation I'd like you help me out for solving the next situation.

ES is a schemaless storage engine. Well, no problem, everything is all right until several users are able to build their schema.

For example, imagine a software product lets to users to tag his/her documents, and each tag has a name and a type. So, user says I want to tag my documents using a tag `project` of type `string`. At the same another user might tag his/her documents tagging them using a tag `project` of type `number`Then ES could index documents using this tag, creating a field on a collection with name tag's name of type string/number... (my server application would serialize documents with this new field).

```
User1:
{ 
   "name": ""
   "department": ""
   "project": "xxx"   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

User2:
{ 
   "name": ""
   "department": ""
   "project": 1000   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

So, I mean each user is able to have his/her own schema.

I would like to ask for you could provide me an approach using only a single index for all users, or using a index per user.

I've to say that the most of the schema is similar for all users. So, all users shares 95% of an initially provided schema, nevertheless, each user is going to be able to add new schema fields...

I hope I've explained well.

Comment: I have to admit that I DO not know ES, so just some general thoughts: If users provide equally named tags with different type, how will ES build the index? Will it contain all values - in your example, strings *and* numbers? If two users provide equally typed and named tags, does ES provide means to get only the tags of a specific user? Imagine user 1 finding documents of user 2 that accidentially are tagged such that they match 1st user's search pattern. May I assume this is not desired?

Answer (score 0):

If your users are able to create their own fields (having the same name but potentially different types, i.e. string vs integer), it's best to have one index per user, otherwise you'll run into issues if you're using ES 2.0 or higher.

Concretely, as of ES 2.0, having two fields with the same name but different settings (diff type, diff analyzer, etc) in two different mapping types of the same index [is not allowed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#merging-conflicts).

Comment: Did this help? Do you need more info?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Val's answer, let me give you some general advice: Yes, consider everybody's advice, but carefully, especially if it is given in such a general manner. What generally is a good practice may still be not applicable or at least not suitable for the specific case. If you have good reasons not to follow the good practice, do so!

Example: I assume that it is not desired that user A finds documents of other users (B, C, ...), just because they match user A's search criteria. Provided ES does *not* provide appropriate means itself, a global index would impose you a lot of work extra work to identify the tags of a specific user (e. g. disallowing any tag type other than string, prefixing every tag value with user name and a separator character - which would possibly have to be escaped in the user name, if allowed there - and coping all the time with this extension). In this specific case, even if a global index was allowed, it would be much easier/more pragmatical to use an index per user.